# ros2 launch foo.yaml with composable nodes and setting log level

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, yaml

I'm using a `launch.yaml` like this:

```
launch:
    - node_container:
        pkg: rclcpp_components
        exec: component_container
        name: my_container
        namespace: ''
        composable_node:
            -   pkg: rosbag2_transport # New rolling node
                plugin: rosbag2_transport::Player
                name: bag_player
                namespace: ''
                # arguments: ['--ros-args', '--log-level', 'debug']
                # args: ['--ros-args', '--log-level', 'debug']
                # ros-args: ['--log-level', 'debug']
                param:
                # - name: logging_level
                #   value: 'debug'
```

However, I'd like to enable DEBUG logging, but none of the options I've tried (see the commented-out lines) have worked, and there is scant documentation on the format. Has anyone got this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Experimenting as I wrote the question, I finally found the required lines:

```
launch:
    - node_container:
        pkg: rclcpp_components
        exec: component_container
        name: my_container
        namespace: ''
        args: '--ros-args --log-level debug'
        composable_node:
            -   pkg: rosbag2_transport # New rolling node
                plugin: rosbag2_transport::Player
                name: bag_player
                namespace: ''
                param:
```

I'm leaving this as a self-answer as it may help someone else with a similar issue.